# How to add a docker-registry secret for Google Cloud Platform on Windows (that is, in PowerShell, not Bash)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm using Windows, Docker for Windows with Kubernetes enabled and PowerShell (not Bash). This is just for local testing of my Docker images and Kubernetes set up. The problem I'm having is getting access to Google's Container Registry.

I created the service account, hopefully with the right permissions but I'm not there yet. I've got the JSON file with the private key and other details. My problem is when I try to create the secret by running:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gcr-json-key --docker-server=eu.gcr.io --docker-username=_json_key --docker-password="$(cat json_credentials.json)" --docker-email=pupeno@example.com
```

I get this error:

```
error: exactly one NAME is required, got 5
See 'kubectl create secret docker-registry -h' for help and examples.
```

My guess is that after `--docker-password="` I end up with line-feeds, quotes, etc. and that is causing the problem. Or is it something else? How am I suppose to do it? Does this work in Bash but not PowerShell?

Comment: This issue does not appear to be reproducible on my end. I also compare yoru syntax the one used in this [article](https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/). However, I would say to make sure that you are using `bash` and not powershell and also make sure that you are putting the line breaks (\) so that the command is not wrapping which may cause issues.

Comment: I'm on Windows, running bash is super quirky at best. I'm sure in bash it works fine as this article and command was written when using bash.

Comment: Yes, I also tried in `bash` and had no issues. Did you check to make sure that the line breaks were also added in your command.

Comment: @pupeno Did you solve this issue? I'm having the exact same issue, and I noticed it disappears when I use ' instead of " in my json, however this is not a valid json. Using bash is a struggle, because my entire setup with kubectl etc. is on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by escaping double quotes and removing new lines from the JSON key file. (Powershell)

```
$JSON_CREDS = "C:\Path\To\Creds.json"
$REPOSITORY_HOST = "https://gcr.io"
$EMAIL = "email@example.com"
# An arbitrary string to serve as the name of the secret
$SECRET_NAME = "gcr-pull-secret"
$KUB_NAMESPACE = "some-namespace"

$service_json = (Get-Content $JSON_CREDS).replace("\n", "").replace('"', '\"')

$kubePath = "C:\Path\To\kubectl.exe"
$namespaceArg = "--namespace=$KUB_NAMESPACE"
$createArg = "create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME"
$serverArg = "--docker-server=$REPOSITORY_HOST"
$usernameArg = "--docker-username=_json_key"
$passwordArg = "--docker-password=""$service_json"""
$emailArg = "--docker-email=$EMAIL"

Start-Process $kubePath -ArgumentList "$namespaceArg $createArg $serverArg $usernameArg $passwordArg $emailArg" -Wait -NoNewWindow

# Optional, used to patch the default service account

$imagePullSecretJson = """{\""imagePullSecrets\"": [{\""name\"": \""$SECRET_NAME\""}]}"""

Start-Process $kubePath -ArgumentList "patch serviceaccount default -p $imagePullSecretJson" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```